# Biased dice with strange probabilities

Tags: probability, generating-functions, dice

[A recent question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4487334/25554), probably soon to be deleted, mentions:

> … two weighted d6 dice. … there is a 40% chance of getting a sum of 12, and a uniform distribution for all other possible sums.

This seemed unlikely, but I was not able to rule it out.  I would like to find out:

> Is there any possible assignment of probabilities to the twelve faces of two cubes, and assignment of a non-negative integer number of pips to the faces, to produce the required probabilities?

To be clear, there must be an $0.4$ probability of rolling a 12, and a $0.06$ probability of rolling each integer from 2 to 11 inclusive.

To my surprise I could not even prove that this was impossible when the cubes had the usual number of pips on each face. (Lulu's answer below gives a simple argument that proves the result for this case.)

I tagged this with [generating-functions](/questions/tagged/generating-functions) because that seemed like a fruitful approach, although I have not tried it yet.

Comment: It is not possible if the dice are independent

Comment: You can achieve your result if one of the dice has a single pip on each side and the other has $11$ sides with $1,2,\ldots,11$ pips with the $11$ pip side having probability $0.4$ then you can get your result.  But you may want each die to have six sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following we make no assumption on the number of sides of these dice, except that they have more than one, so we
may assume that for either die, a number of pips appears only on one side.

Let $a_h, a_l$ be the probability of throwing the highest and the lowest number of pips on the first die, and $b_h, b_l$
the same for the second die. Then we must have $a_hb_h = 0.4$ (with those highest values summing to 12) and $a_lb_l =
0.06$ (with those lowest values summing to 2). Since $a_ha_lb_hb_l = 0.024$, at least one of $a_hb_l$ and $a_lb_h$ must
be greater than or equal to $\sqrt{0.024} \approx 0.15 > 0.06$, a contradiction.

Comment: +1 - this was my thought in my comments to the original question, with your "more than one" being essential.  Otherwise, suppose the first die gives a constant in which case having $a_lb_h>0.06$ is not a problem as it corresponds to a total of $12$.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't (assuming independence of the two dice, and assuming the usual face values)

Let $\{p_i\}$ denote the probabilities on the first die, and $\{\psi_i\}$ the probabilities on the second.

Then $$p_6\times \psi_6=.4\implies \psi_6=\frac {.4}{p_6}$$
and
$$p_1\times \psi_1=.06\implies \psi_1=\frac {.06}{p_1}$$

But then the probability of getting a $7$ must be $.06$ so $$p_1\psi_6+p_6\psi_1≤.06\implies x\times .4+\frac {.06}x≤.06$$

where $x=\frac {p_1}{p_6}$.

But $.4x+\frac {.06}x$ has  a minimum value of about $.31$ for positive $x$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks.  Do you have any thoughts on how to approach the much-less-constrained problem where the dice may have nonstandard numbers of pips?

Comment: @MJD  Yeah, that one seems more slippery.  I suppose one has to establish lots of requirements on the two sets of faces, and then apply an argument similar to mine.  The core concept seems simple enough:  given the known value at the two extremes, the middle cases can't have such a low probability.  Maybe you don't need much to push that through.

Comment: "Slippery" is a good description for it.  I agree it's probably straightforward but tedious.

Comment: @MJD For instance, if one die is fair and the other can only come up $1,6$ equally., then every sum has probability $\frac 12\times \frac 16$ except for the middle value which has probability $\frac 16$.  That you can do, but you can't shift all the probability to an extreme.  I think.

Comment: Mees de Vries killed this one dead, I think.  Thanks again for your contributions!